# Can't start an emacsclient process with xbindkeys

Tags: key-bindings, emacsclient

I'm trying to launch the Emacs calculator with the XF86Calc key. I have

```
"emacsclient -c -e '(calc nil t)'" XF86Calc
```

in ~/.xbindkeysrc

I can launch it from "Run Action" in xbindkeys-config. But pressing XF86Calc doesn't do anything. How does one use xbindkeys to launch an emacsclient frame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid mistake on my part. The keycode is XF86Calculator and not XF86Calc. The xbindkeysrc line works fine with the right keycode.